# Can a level 11 Warlock do 78 damage in one turn with Eldritch Blast and Magic Stone?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, warlock

Can I do at maximum 78 dmg in one turn with the following stats?

Warlock level 11 stats:

- Spellcasting modifier: Charisma 20 equals +5
- Eldritch Invocations:
  Agonizing Blast
- 1 magic stone max: 1d6 + 5 equals max 11
- 1 eldritch blast : 1d10 + 5 (of agonizing blast) equals max 15

So because I'm level 11 and assuming the 3 stones that I send at the same time that I'm sending the eldritch blast because it's a ranged spell attack it's 45+33 equals 78 max.

Comment: *Eldritch blast* can't send anything - it only targets creatures. If you cast it on a stone then nothing will happen.

Answer (score 20):

## No

Enchanting the stones is a bonus action, **but you need another action to throw or hurl them**.

Attacking with a ranged weapon is an action, so is casting Eldritch blast. Furthermore if you don't have **Extra attack** or **Multiattack: Volley** you can throw just one stone in an action.

This means, you can throw/hurl stones **or** use eldritch blast in one action. You would need another action to do the other thing.

Comment: Can you clarify that each stone needs a ranged spell attack (which is an action) in order to do damage? You cannot throw them all at once

Comment: @PremierBromanov Read carefully. "You or someone else can make a ranged spell attack with one of the pebbles by throwing it or hurling it with a sling." **With one of the pebbles**

Comment: I send the stone with the eldritch blast which is a ranged spell attack so it hits, the eldritch blast is the other action.

Magic stone is just a bonus action.

Comment: Why do you thing that you can do both things at once?

Comment: @Momonga-sama I read carefully it says throwing it, or hurling it with a sling, which means: I can only hurl it with a sling but throwing it could be done by hand, which means with the Eldritch Blast no?

Comment: No, you need one action to throw the stone. Period. Casting eldritch blast is other action. Period.

Comment: @Momonga-sama That's what I said, is it not? You cannot throw more than 1 pebble in a turn unless someone else throws it.

Comment: @PremierBromanov Correct. You wanted me to clarify that.

Comment: @Momonga-sama Yes, but this is not indicated in your answer. That's what I meant. The asker is under the impression that you can throw all 3 pebbles at once.

Comment: @Momonga-sama not at once, but don't you forget I'm a level 11 Warlock my Eldritch blast can cast 3 beams with only 1 cast of magic stone I get 3 pebbles imbued with magic, me or anyone else can use them while using a ranged spell attack.

I make 3 ranged spell attacks in this case 3 Eldritch Blasts with on each of them I use the pebble, I don't see it that hard to comprehend.

Comment: Why are you so stubborn? By casting the spell, (not attacking with magical beams) you spend one action. You can't use them in the round, that you cast a spell that takes one action. Someone else, or you in next turn is able to use the stones, like i described.

Comment: I think the confusion comes from @likewyise reading the description as if : "You or someone else can make a ranged spell attack [along] with one of the pebbles by throwing it or hurling it with a sling". It's clear from the grammar that throwing the pebble *is* the ranged spell attack, not something done *in addition to* or *as a contingency of* a separate ranged spell attack.

Comment: @keithcurtis correct but that part once it was edited was remove, I particularly put bold font on that part, because Eldritch blast is a ranged spell attack I'm just doing what magic stone tell me to.

Do a ranged spell attack which I'm doing.

Comment: But that's not how it reads. The ranged spell attack you are making refers to the actual attack with the stone, not making a different ranged spell attack.

Comment: I think someone needs to prove that the ranged spell attack is an action by itself. The wording is the same between the spells, yet Eldritch Blast has a casting time of 1 action and yet doesn't require an extra action to make the spell attack. Magic stone, however, is a bonus action to create, but the action economy isn't specified for the attack.  Therein lies the issue.

Comment: I think you are reading something into the cantrip that isn't there. It's a way to make little magical missiles that you can use yourself or let a friend use. They are not something done in addition to an entirely separate spell. When you attack someone with them, they attack magically, using the caster's spell attack bonus instead of a normal missile weapon attack. That's why it specifies whose bonus is used when making the attack. It uses the caster's spell attack bonus. It literally says "**make a ranged spell attack** with one of the pebbles **by throwing it or hurling it with a sling**"

Comment: Rather than continue this in comment, I have constructed my own answer. :)

Answer (score 7):

**This is incorrect.**

The Magic Stone cantrip is not triggered by a ranged spell attack. It allows you to use a bonus action to create a small supply of magical stones that you can use to attack people using the mechanic of a ranged spell attack. The "ranged spell attack" in the cantrip description is the act of using the stone you created at casting time. It has nothing to do with the casting of another spell.

You could cast the cantrip as a bonus action, and then use your Action to make a ranged spell attack and throw one of the stones or to cast Eldritch Blast.

However, you could not both cast Eldritch Blast and throw a stone in a single turn. It might be possible if you double classed with a second class that grants you a second attack, since throwing or shooting the stone is a "ranged spell attack" and not "casting a spell". This is not the case with a straight 11th level warlock, though.

This is upheld by a [question](https://mobile.twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/738128058746474496) asked of Jeremy Crawford, presumably by someone here, since the wording is so similar.

The conversation goes back and forth for a bit, but the pertinent quotes are:

> Jeremy Crawford: Eldritch blast doesn't hurl objects
>
> Jeremy Crawford:The act of hurling a magic stone is the ranged spell attack.

Comment: regarding the second paragraph, why can't you cast them together? both are cantrips, one has a casting time of a bonus action and the other a casting time of 1 action.

Comment: That is correct. I hadn't considered that. I have amended. And thanks for the grammar fixes. I was typing that in a hurry.

Comment: @likewyise Sorry if the quote from Crawford was a breach of etiquette. I didn't go searching it out. I regularly follow his feed and that jumped out at me, given the earlier discussion.